# Змейка Unity 5 C# noobtuts

Tags: c#, unity3d

[Есть такой мануал по змейке от Noobtuts](http://noobtuts.com/unity/2d-snake-game)

Сделал змейку по нему, всё хорошо, добавил разное от себя, но вот проблема - ведёт себя некорректно хвост. А именно - после съедания  3 "яблока" начинает делать дырки в хвосте, если змейка ползёт горизонтально, и хвост ползет ступеньками параллельно телу, если змейка ползёт вертикально. Наглядно на видео, ютуб. https://youtu.be/YR6lfFX5xEI

Код самой змейки

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class Snake2: MonoBehaviour {
    public Text tt;
    int score = 0;

    public void ClickTestu() {
        dir = Vector2.up; // This code is executed every frame that the RepeatButton remains clicked
    }
    public void ClickTestd() {
        dir = -Vector2.up; // This code is executed every frame that the RepeatButton remains clicked
    }
    public void ClickTestl() {
        dir = Vector2.left; // This code is executed every frame that the RepeatButton remains clicked
    }
    public void ClickTestr() {
        dir = Vector2.right; // This code is executed every frame that the RepeatButton remains clicked
    }
    // Did the snake eat something?
    bool ate = false;

    // Tail Prefab
    public GameObject tailPrefab;
    List < Transform > tail = new List < Transform > ();
    Vector2 dir = Vector2.right;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start() {
        InvokeRepeating("Move", 0.3 f, 0.3 f);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {
        tt.text = "Score " + score;
    }
    void Move() {
        // Save current position (gap will be here)
        Vector2 v = transform.position;

        // Move head into new direction (now there is a gap)
        transform.Translate(dir);

        // Ate something? Then insert new Element into gap
        if (ate) {
            // Load Prefab into the world
            GameObject g = (GameObject) Instantiate(tailPrefab,
                v,
                Quaternion.identity);

            // Keep track of it in our tail list
            tail.Insert(0, g.transform);

            // Reset the flag
            ate = false;

        }
        // Do we have a Tail?
        else if (tail.Count > 0) {
            // Move last Tail Element to where the Head was
            tail.Last().position = v;

            // Add to front of list, remove from the back
            tail.Insert(0, tail.Last());
            tail.RemoveAt(tail.Count - 1);
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D coll) {
        // Food?
        if (coll.name.StartsWith("food")) {
            // Get longer in next Move call
            ate = true;
            // Remove the Food
            Destroy(coll.gameObject);
            score++;
        }
        // Collided with Tail or Border
        else {
            dir = -Vector2.up; // ToDo 'You lose' screen
        }
    }
```

Вопрос - как избежать такого и что сделать чтобы хвост нормально следовал за головой, клеточка за клеточкой?

Comment: Очень интересно. А в чём состоит ваш вопрос?

Comment: @VladD Добавил вопрос в вопрос.

Comment: В причине закрытия акцент на слове **минимальный**.

Answer (score 0):

ну может я и слепой, но я не вижу где прописано чтоб предыдущий объект из списка запоминал местоположение нынешнего объекта, и так по цепочке для каждого объекта. У тебя написано что хвост двигается в сторону где была голова, но чтоб сделать чтоб он запоминал позицию нынешнего, нужно это прописать. У тебя скажем так только пол кода. Остальное тебе нужно дописать самому.